Varieties where every algebra is saturated
In the context of universal algebra, given any signature $\Omega$, and an $\Omega$-algebra $X$, if there are two distinct operation symbols $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega$ of the same arity such that
$${\omega_1}_X = {\omega_2}_X$$
Then we call $X$ unsaturated, if it is not unsaturated, it is called saturated. The zero algebra (the algebra consisting of only a single element) is always unsaturated (as long as there are two distinct operation symbols in the signature of the same arity). But some varieties over signatures which permit unsaturated algebras, have the property that no algebra except the zero algebra is unsaturated. An example is commutative rings with unity. Here's why:
Suppose a commutative ring $(R,+,\cdot, 0,1)$ has the property that for any $x,y\in R$,
$$x+y = x\cdot y$$
Then in particular,
$$1+1 = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$$
Hence $ 1= 0 $ so for any $x\in R$ we have
$$ x = 1\cdot x = 0\cdot x = 0 $$
Hence $R=\{0\}$. So every non-trivial algebra in this variety is saturated.
In the variety of vector spaces, every non-trivial algebra is also saturated, since given a non-zero vector $x$ one can prove the implication
$$ r_1 \cdot x = r_2 \cdot x \implies r_1 = r_2 $$
Where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are scalars. This seems like a really nice property for a variety to have, and so my questions are

Is this a notion that has been defined and studied previously?

Can we classify those varieties which have only saturated algebras?


The second question is of course a tall ask, but any sufficient conditions would be interesting, and for a more concrete question,

We have seen that there is a variety with only binary and nullary operations where every non-trivial algebra is saturated (ring with unity) but to prove that every vector space is saturated, one crucially relies on the existence of a binary operation, namely vector addition. So it is natural to ask if there are varieties with only nullary and unary, or only nullary, or only binary etc. operations which have this property. I am particularly interested in examples where each operation symbol has "minimal arity", by this I mean that it is not the case that any of the operations are independent of any of their arguments, in every algebra. Since in a case like this, one can replace that operation with one which has strictly smaller arity, and obtain a variety which is isomorphic to the original variety.


@amrsa you are of course right,  see the current edit.

Nice question! I guess for the third question you mean to require that there are at least two unary symbols, and the variety contains a non-zero algebra. I don't understand exactly why your assumption about trivialising equations in your answer to the third question is justified, and why you say below that this gives a complete answer. Do you not care about the variety over two function symbols $f$ and $g$ subject to the equation $f(g(x)) = g(f(y))$ for example? Setting $f=g=\mathrm{id}$ never satisfies this equation except for in the zero algebra, but there are nontrivial unsaturated models.

@IzaakvanDongen Perhaps that will give something interesting, I'm not sure. But notice that it follows from that equality that $fg$ and $gf$ are constant. For it follows immediately that $fg(x)=gf(x)$, and so $gf(x)=gf(y)$, whence $gf$ is constant; for $fg$ it is analogous. From $fg(x)=gf(x)$ it follows also that the constant is the same regardless of the order of the operations.

@IzaakvanDongen you are correct, my assertion was a bit naive, my intention was to exclude the case of unary symbols which "behave as" nullary ones, and I thought my assumption achieved exactly this but I see I was a bit hasty.

Let $\mathbf X = (\{0,1\},f,g)$, where $f(0)=f(1)=0$, and $g(x)=x$, and let $\mathscr V$ be the variety generated by $\mathbf X$.
Notice that $f$ is constant and $g$ is the identity for every algebra in $\mathscr V$.
If $\mathbf A \in \mathscr V$ and $f^{\mathbf A}=g^{\mathbf A}$, then for $a,b \in A$,
$$a = g(a) = f(a) = f(b) = g(b) = b,$$
whence $\mathbf A$ is trivial.

Interesting, thank you. Considering this is a variety, it has some collection of identities defining it. Do you have any idea what these identities might be? I'm guessing $g(x)=x$ would be one of them, and $f(f(x)) = x$ but this doesn't exclude the algebra $({0,1},f,g)$ where $f(x)=g(x)=x$

I changed $f$ so that it actually works as though it is a nullary operation. The result is actually simpler, although you may find it somewhat trivial...

My mistake in the first example was certainly the assumption that the given algebra would be the only subdirectly irreducible in the variety. This one doesn't even deal with that concept or others such as subdirect products.

I see, thank you for the update, I agree that it works, and I also do consider it to be a trivial counterexample since $f$ could literally be replaced with a nullary operation to produce a variety which is "isomorphic" to this one, wherein we again have only one unary operation. But the other case is addressed in my edit, jointly providing a complete answer to the third question. Thank you!

I will accept your answer if no one provides an answer to the first and second questions after a sufficient time period

This is a modification of the answer given by amrsa.
There is indeed a non-trivial variety over a signature over with two unital symbols, which is not isomorphic to a variety with only one unary, and one nullary symbol, such that every algebra except the zero-algebra is saturated. Let the signature be $\Omega= \{f,g\}$ and let the variety be all those $\Omega$-algebras satisfying the two identities:
$$ g(x) = x \\
f(f(x)) = f(f(y))$$
Clearly in any non-trivial algebra we have $f\neq g$, further, this variety contains at least one algebra where $f$ is not constant, one can take $f$ to be the linear map associated with any matrix which is not zero, but squares to the zero matrix for example, and $g$ to be the identity. The follow up question is then, how many unary operations can be distinguished without the help of a binary operation?

@amrsa, this is not an issue, as the zero algebra is deliberately excluded from consideration, since it is always unsaturated (provided you have multiple operations of the same arity) and hence not interesting to consider. The proof that $f$ and $g$ are distinct otherwise is quite simple: suppose $f$ is the identity, then the identity is constant, so we are in the zero algebra.

And in fact, I have found varieties where one can separate, $4$, $5$, and $6$ unary symbols, but $3$ eludes me. I will be posting a question about this soon, and I would appreciate your feedback @amrsa ! Your theoretical/abstract knowledge of universal algebra provides a nice alternative to my thinking

@amrsa it's not an issue for $f$ to be constant in some algebras, I just don't want it to be deducible from the equations that $f$ is constant, equivalently, that $f$ is constant in every algebra

Ok, I see your point now
